# KVO Global scope

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing, property-observer

I am learning MVVM so I added observer on property

```
 init(model: RegisterUserModel = RegisterUserModel()) {
    self.registerModel = model

    let confirmPasswordObserver = self.registerModel.observe(\RegisterUserModel.confirmPassword) {[unowned self] (model, value) in
        print("Confrim Password Observeer called with value :\(self.registerModel.confirmPassword)")
    }
   // self.registerModel.confirmPassword = "CALLED WITH THIS LINE INSIDE INIT FUNC ONLY" 


}
```

observer should be called when textfield value change from view controller so I have  set `registerModel.confirmPassword = str` from **updateField**  Method

**But `print` statement is not been executed**

but if I change value from `init`  method then observer is working !!

How to make it global ?

**EXTRA Info**

How I change property

```
extension RegisterViewModel {

    func updateField (field:RegisterFields, withString str:String) {
        switch field {
        case .firstName:
            registerModel.firstName = str

        case .lastName:
            registerModel.lastName = str

        case .email:
            registerModel.email = str

        case .phone:
            registerModel.phone = str

        case .city:
            registerModel.city = str

        case .password:
            registerModel.password = str
            confirmPassword.value = confirmPassword.value

        case .confirmPassword:
            registerModel.confirmPassword = str //SHOULD BE CALLED FROM HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear !!

I have added global object for

```
private var confirmPasswordObserver : NSKeyValueObservation?
```

and use this object.

```
  confirmPasswordObserver = self.registerModel.observe(\RegisterUserModel.confirmPassword) {[unowned self] (model, value) in
            print("Confrim Password Observeer called with value :\(self.registerModel.confirmPassword)")
        }
```

And it is **working** now. But I wonder if any one can exaplin this to me. even though confirmPasswordObserver is unused still it need global scope

Hope some one can take help from it so I decided not to delete this

Comment: My guess is that compiler is just getting rid off the local scope constant at compile time because the observer value is not used until the moment something actually changes and there's no guarantee that it will even happen. On a global scope though, reference to the object is kept after the initialization. I'm not 100% sure that that's the issue, but that's just my idea.